# Slow method that works with IEnumerable<dynamic> as input and return value

Tags: c#, .net

I have this method that returns an IEnumerable list , it takes 5 seconds to execute , so I want to know how can I optimize it side performance time of response.

```
private IEnumerable<dynamic> GetData(IEnumerable<dynamic> listD)
{
    List<dynamic> data = new List<dynamic>();

    foreach (var item in listD)
    {
        var allPro = item?.Pro?.Select(x => new RepHelper
        {
            Res = x.Rep,
            Title = x.Title
        });

        string allRep = "";

        if (allPro.Any())
        {
            allRep = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(allPro);
        }

        data.Add(new
        {
            Id = item.Id,
            Auteur = item?.AspNetUsers?.Init ?? "",
            NiveauCode = item?.Niveau?.Code ?? "",
            NiveauTextColeur = item?.Niveau?.TextColeur ?? "",
            Rep = item?.Pro?.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Rep == true)?.Title ?? "",
            IdParent = item?.Id_Parent ?? -1,
            allReponse = allRep,
        });
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Comment: I have rolled back Rev 2 → 1. Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I would start by not ever using `dynamic` in performance-sensitive code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq `Select` and `FirstOrDefault(Func)` both have internal iterators, as well as `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`. So, if you count them, then you have at least 4 iterators going inside your method. You can at reduce that by combining `Select` and `FirstOrDefault(Func)` with a single iterator something like :

```
private IEnumerable<dynamic> GetData(IEnumerable<dynamic> listD)
{
    List<dynamic> data = new List<dynamic>();
    
    foreach (var item in listD)
    {
        if(item == null) continue;

        var responseList = new List<RepHelper>();

        string repTitle; 
        
        if(item?.Pro != null)
        {
            foreach(var pro in item.Pro)
            {
                if(pro == null) continue;
                
                var rep = new RepHelper { Res = pro.Rep, Title = pro.Title };
                
                if(repTitle == null && rep.Res == true)
                {                   
                    repTitle = rep.Title;                   
                }                               
            
                responseList.Add(rep);
            }
        }   
        
        data.Add(new
        {
            Id = item.Id,
            Auteur = item?.AspNetUsers?.Init ?? string.Empty,
            NiveauCode = item?.Niveau?.Code ?? string.Empty,
            NiveauTextColeur = item?.Niveau?.TextColeur ?? string.Empty,
            Rep = repTitle ?? string.Empty,
            IdParent = item?.Id_Parent ?? -1,
            allReponse = responseList.Count > 0 ? JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responseList) : string.Empty,
        });
    }
    
    return data;
}
```

Now, since you're returning `IEnumerable`, why not use `yield return` instead of initializing a `List<dynamic>` ? so your work would be like :

```
private IEnumerable<dynamic> GetData(IEnumerable<dynamic> listD)
{
    foreach (var item in listD)
    {
        // same code here ....
        
        
        yield return new
        {
            Id = item.Id,
            Auteur = item?.AspNetUsers?.Init ?? string.Empty,
            NiveauCode = item?.Niveau?.Code ?? string.Empty,
            NiveauTextColeur = item?.Niveau?.TextColeur ?? string.Empty,
            Rep = repTitle ?? string.Empty,
            IdParent = item?.Id_Parent ?? -1,
            allReponse = responseList.Count > 0 ? JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responseList) : string.Empty,
        };
    }
}
```

You can also go `IEnumerable` all the way, with something like this :

```
private string _repTitle; 
private bool _hasRepHelperCollection;

private IEnumerable<dynamic> GetData(IEnumerable<dynamic> source)
{
    foreach (var item in source)
    {   
        if(item != null)
        {
            _hasRepHelperCollection = false;
            _repTitle = null;
    
            var allPro = GetRepHelper(item?.Pro);

            yield return new
            {
                Id = item.Id,
                Auteur = item?.AspNetUsers?.Init ?? string.Empty,
                NiveauCode = item?.Niveau?.Code ?? string.Empty,
                NiveauTextColeur = item?.Niveau?.TextColeur ?? string.Empty,
                Rep = _repTitle ?? string.Empty,
                IdParent = item?.Id_Parent ?? -1,
                allReponse = _hasRepHelperCollection ? JsonConvert.SerializeObject(allPro) : string.Empty
            };
            
        }
    }
}

private IEnumerable<RepHelper> GetRepHelper(IEnumerable<dynamic> source)
{
    if(source == null)
        yield break;
    
    foreach(var item in source)
    {
        if(item != null)
        {
            var rep = new RepHelper { Res = response.Rep, Title = response.Title };
            
            if(_repTitle == null && rep.Rep)
            {                   
                _repTitle = rep.Title;
            }                               
            
            if(!hasRepHelperCollection)
                _hasRepHelperCollection = true;
            
            yield return rep;
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Other than the general rule of "don't use `dynamic` if you don't have to", there's not much to optimize here. The serialization to JSON is probably your hot spot. However, you can pre-allocate your final list size like so:

`List<dynamic> data = new List<dynamic>(listD.Count());`

and that will buy you fewer reallocations, depending on the number of items you're passing in.

However, back to "Don't use `dynamic`: your anonymous type is all `dynamic`s due to the nature of the assignment, but it seems that you know most of them are `string`s while a couple are (probably) `int`s. So define a type:

```
public class FinalData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Auteur { get; set; }

    public string NiveauCode { get; set; }

    public string NiveauTextColeur { get; set; }

    public string Rep { get; set; }

    public int IdParent { get; set; }

    public string allReponse { get; set; }
}
```

And it can still be assigned to a `dynamic` member of the `List<dynamic>` as you do. So here is the following code (note, I also combined your `if` into a ternary in the assignment to tighten things up:

```
    private IEnumerable<dynamic> GetData(IEnumerable<dynamic> listD)
    {
        List<dynamic> data = new List<dynamic>(listD.Count());

        foreach (var item in listD)
        {
            var allPro = ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)item?.Pro)?.Select(x => new RepHelper
            {
                Res = x.Rep,
                Title = x.Title
            });

            data.Add(new FinalData
            {
                Id = item?.Id ?? -1,
                Auteur = item?.AspNetUsers?.Init ?? string.Empty,
                NiveauCode = item?.Niveau?.Code ?? string.Empty,
                NiveauTextColeur = item?.Niveau?.TextColeur ?? string.Empty,
                Rep = ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)item?.Pro)?.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Rep)?.Title ?? string.Empty,
                IdParent = item?.Id_Parent ?? -1,
                allReponse = allPro?.Any() == true ? JsonConvert.SerializeObject(allPro) : string.Empty,
            });
        }

        return data;
    }
```

Now, important most of all: **You** need to define what is acceptable performance of the method. Five seconds is too slow. Measure twice, cut once is an old adage which applies quite well to software development.

Comment: I have tested the line of initialisation of the list data  with pre allocation size listD.Count() this is take 1174 ms but without specifying the size it takes only 1 ms I have tested with PerfTips in visual studio , so here pre allocation list size dosn't speed up the method note that my count list is only 20 element what do you think ?

Comment: @mecab95 Make an interface out of the object type and have that be the list type. Returning `List<IDataItem>` is fine. Also, only reason I'm not upvoting is `== true`.

Comment: @T145  what is the advantage of using an interface here over a class type for DataItem in thé side of thé performance ?